# Swift core data at once very slow

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I am finishing new version of swift application and I notice that loading from core data become very slow. Same code in last version of app works great but in new it's very slow. Code is below and it's 100% same like in last version but now I must wait for cache 5-6 seconds and cache data are also same when testing old and new version!

I already lost few days for this, waiting to resolve so I can publish updated app. I printed index just to see how much it take time to print about all 600 index, and in last version it's max 1 sec, in new version same code about 5-6 sec!

I just find that ObjectTMP.init(... take time in newest version and it doesn't in last version. I will investigate it a little bit more

Any help with this.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // load

        //We need to create a context from this container
        let managedContext = self.appDelegate.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()

        //Prepare the request of type NSFetchRequest  for the entity
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Cache")

        do {
            let result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

             var j = 0

             for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                 ...   
                 hash[String(Int(data.value(forKey: "id") as! String)] = ObjectTMP.init( ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If u are testing on simulator or connected device at first you should delete

```
print("j:" + j.description)
```

When u load big amount of data it will slow it a lot, because u have loop there, I guess You add this "print" statement for dev purpose.

Comment: Yes just for dev purpose to see if that loop take lot of time, and yes that loop take time, 5-6 sec, no matter if there is print and only in new version, not in last version which is same, maybe there is some project configuration which make problem

Answer (score 0):

CryptoSwift newest version makes problem. I use swift 4.2 and for that version I should use <= 0.15 CryptoSwift, and I was using 1.3. With 0.15 everything works like it should, there is no delay of 5-6 seconds.